# Ubuntu redirect output

Tags: ubuntu

I have the function:

`function >> file.txt`

this creates the file.txt in my current directory. I have a folder log in the same directory, how would I request file.txt to be created in my log file (a directory higher)? I tried:

`function >> log/file.txt`

and am unsure why this didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "same directory" you mention is up one directory, then use

```
function >> ../Log/file.txt
```

**..** refers to up one directory, and **.** refers to the current directory. Read up on all this in a [bash tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial)